# How to get spring-boot dependency version in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have a standard spring-boot project with `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin`. i know i can override dependency version with e.g.

```
ext['slf4j.version'] = '1.7.5'
```

but how can i get the version currently imported by spring-boot plugin so i can use it later in the script? for example:

```
currentSlf4jVersion = xxx('slf4j.version')
```

Answer (score 12):

The [dependency management plugin](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin) that Spring Boot's plugin applies for you provides [programmatic access to the properties in imported boms](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/#accessing-properties).

You can get the value of the `slf4j.version` property like this:

```
dependencyManagement.importedProperties['slf4j.version']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find your gradle project dependencies using command

```
gradle dependencies
```

For All:

```
gradle listAllDependencies
```

For sub-project:

```
gradle :<subproject>:dependencies
```

This will output dependencies

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear - i need to get it inside the script, so i can use later

Comment: Once you list your dependencies, you'll see the transitive dependencies and its detail imported by spring-boot.

Comment: @piotrek you define your dependencies in gradle. You can force gradle to include/exclude when resolving dependencies but within your script or code you just use that API. Having all said, you can still determine the API version inside your code programatically but I will not recommend this approach.